# Идентичный текст в h1 и span рассматриваются поисковиком одинаково (SEO)?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация

`<h1>`Продажа человеков, не дорого!`</h1>`
`<span>`Продажа человеков, не дорого!`</span>`

`<h1>` идентичен  по всем параметрам (размер, цвет итп).

Вопросы:

1. Приравняет ли поисковик `<span>` по значимости к `<h1>`?
2. Если п.1 - да, то как грамотнее делать делать крупный текст так, чтобы он выделялся на странице и при этом не влиял на ее ранжирование?

Comment: 1. ХЗ, в SEO много мифов, многие из 2000 годов. 2. `<span class="h1">`, как сделать `.h1` и `h1` одинаковым размером, я думаю, знаете

Comment: конечно знаю, как раз .h1 и использую ))

Comment: мое имхо, на h1 всем плевать. они уже давно рендерят всю страницу, включая JS, и это попадает в сниппет серпа. пример - смотрите в моем профиле

Comment: ну хз, мне кажется h заголовки еще имеют сильное влияние на общий вес страницы

Comment: Сделайте 2 одинаковые страницы на двух поддоменах одного сайта с различием `.h1` и `h1`. Потом посмотрите что выше в выдаче. Я примерно такой опыт скоро поставлю, но не с тегами, а со скоростями генерации страниц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Приравняет ли поисковик span по значимости к h1?

**Разумеется не приравнивает**.

Каждая веб-страница является HTML-документом. Любой документ имеет только одну тему - субъект документа, который в сжатой форме информирует о главном содержании этого документа. Для веб-страницы этим субъектом/темой документа является содержание элемента H1.

Если вы как разработчик хотите создать значимую структуру документа, используйте элементы h1 - h6, чтобы выразить структуру HTML-документа. Проверьте **[документацию W3 Heading](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings/)**. В документации **[HTML Heading W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp)** указано:

> **Заголовки важны**
>
> Поисковые системы используют заголовки для индексации структуры и
> содержимого ваших веб-страниц.

Практически то же самое рекомендует Гугл в своем **[Руководству по поисковой оптимизации для начинающих](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184)**:

> **Для выделения важного текста используйте теги заголовков**
>
> **Рекомендации**
>
> Представьте, что вы пишете обзор.
> Как и при написании обзора большого текста, изложите основные пункты и
> подпункты документа и подумайте, где лучше использовать теги
> заголовков.

Элемент H1 помогает Google лучше понять, что представляет собой ваш контент, чтобы он мог правильно классифицировать его для релевантных поисковых запросов.

Элемент **[span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)** является встроенным элементом который ничего не представляет. Содержание элемента span будет сканировано машинами как простой текст.

Таким образом, применяя элемент span, вместо элемента H1, вы можете создать непонятную структуру веб-документа, которая может вводить поисковики и браузеры в заблуждение.

Создайте эксперимент: создайте два веб-документа - один с элементом span, а другой с элементом H1 и проверьте структуру этих документов на инструменте **[HTML5 Outliner](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/)**. Примерно также это читают машины поисковиков и браузеров.

На практике, вероятно, **[Гугл использует структуру веб-документа](https://research.hubspot.com/winning-googles-featured-snippet)**, созданного с применением элементов H, для выдачи в поиске избранных фрагментов **[Блоки с ответами в Google Поиске](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325)**.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но это итак большинству понятно, вопрос был в другом: неужели поисковик не в состояние понять, что h1 и span/div/p текст в единой стилистике - одно и тоже? Просто поисковики давно понимают, что если цвет текста равен цвету его фона, значит его пытаются обмануть (скрыть текст для пользователя). В моем же вопросе, я пытаюсь как то обмануть поисковик, выдав строчки текста за заголовки, т.е. визуально они заголовки, но технически - нет...

Comment: Элемент H1 - согласно спецификации W3 определяет наиболее важный заголовок - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp . Элемент span не определяет ничего - этот элемент не имеет никакого значения. Боты сканируют элементы, в соответствии с принятым последним стандартом HTML5. Разумеется, боты различают стилистику и цвет, но относиться это к наиболее важному заголовку или же к простому тексту, информируют их вышеуказанные элементы.